# Has anyone successfully used the new usbstor MaximumTransferLength parameter?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, sata, usb-storage

Some time ago, Microsoft added support for specifying the maximum transfer size to the usbstor driver (see KB2581464 at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581464).  I have been unable to actually get the new MaximumTransferLength parameter to work.  I am using Windows 8.

Has anyone successfully used this option such that they can answer a few questions about how they got it to work?

I created a registry key and MaximumTransferLength value for the USB to SATA bridge chip that I am using, as explained in the KB, but it seems to make no difference.

Any thoughts or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What value are you using? The value only is respected if the .inf file is configured to do so

Comment: From your link "For "some" USB storage devices, performance can be improved when you increase the maximum USB transfer size beyond the default setting of 64 KB. This update is supported when the hardware vendor provides a device information file (.inf) to set this value for USB storage devices."  which means it does not work for all devices.

Comment: I'm actually trying to use the parameter to limit the transfer size to debug a hardware problem.  I am designing a SATA device and having problems with disk transfers larger than256 sectors (128K bytes).  The USB/SATA bridge appears to only be sending the request for the first 256 sectors and then hanging.  Is there actually a separate inf file for each USB/SATA bridge chip?  I am using ASMedia 1x53 chips right now.